# How to fix too large fonts in Chromium's title bar, menu and bookmark toolbar?

Tags: fonts, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Chromium version 37.0.2062.94. As you can see fonts in title bar, menu and bookmark bar are too big and ugly. Does someone know how to fix this error?

[image: Example screenshot]